# How do I merge partial data and format it in R?

Tags: r

So I have this R file:

```
# Open CSV file
df <- read.table("myfile.txt", header = FALSE, sep = ":", dec = "-")

# Delete the first column
df <- df[-1]

# Delete every 3rd and 4th columns
i1 <- rep(seq(3, ncol(df), 4) , each = 2) + 0:1
df <- df[,-i1]

# Remove extra text from columns
df[] <- lapply(df, gsub, pattern = ",title", replacement = "", fixed = TRUE)
df[] <- lapply(df, gsub, pattern = ",url", replacement = "", fixed = TRUE)

# Swap columns around so title comes before ID
df <- data.frame(new_col = paste0('"', df[seq(2, ncol(df), 2)], '#', df[seq(1, ncol(df)-1, 2)], '"', ','))

# Write to file
write.table(df, file = "result.lua", sep = "#", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```

And this is myfile.txt:

```
(new AudioControls()).init([{"id":53201,"title":"bbc-two intro","url":"https:\/\/wow.bbc.com\/bbc-ids\/classic\/enus\/209\/53201","type":"audio\/mpeg"},{"id":53227,"title":"bbc - demo04","url":"https:\/\/wow.bbc.com\/bbc-ids\/classic\/enus\/235\/53227","type":"audio\/mpeg"},{"id":53301,"title":"bbc-horizon quality","url":"https:\/\/wow.bbc.com\/bbc-ids\/classic\/enus\/53\/53301","type":"audio\/mpeg"}], WH.ge('temporal-fixation'), {});
```

And when run, this is what it produces (result.txt):

```
"bbc-two intro#53201",
"bbc - demo04#53227",
"bbc-horizon quality#53301",
```

So it takes the numeric ID and title from myfile.txt and it puts it in the format title#id.  All good so far.

However, what I need to do is change the titles.  So I have another file called base.txt.  This is base.txt.

```
53201;streets/faculties/travelguide.txt
121597;zones/sunburn/fatality_02.txt
53227;stems/futures/holiday.txt
121599;quiz/question/functional.mp3
121600;alone/future/suicide.dat
121601;crossroads/valley/melbourne.dec
```

So what I want is for the IDs that exist in both myfile.txt and base.txt to be merged somewhat so that the output shows the ID that exists in both but the title is only from base.txt.

So the desired output would be this:

```
"streets/faculties/travelguide.txt#53201",
"stems/futures/holiday.txt#53227",
```

With the quotes and commas as shown.  Note that only the IDs that exist in both myfile.txt and base.txt should be shown in the new table.

Can someone tell me how to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me -

```
df <- read.table("myfile.txt", header = FALSE, sep = ":", dec = "-")
df <- df[-1]

# Delete every 3rd and 4th columns
i1 <- rep(seq(3, ncol(df), 4) , each = 2) + 0:1
df <- df[,-i1]

# Remove extra text from columns
df[] <- lapply(df, gsub, pattern = ",title", replacement = "", fixed = TRUE)
df[] <- lapply(df, gsub, pattern = ",url", replacement = "", fixed = TRUE)

#Read base.txt
base <- read.table('base.txt', sep = ';')
#Keep only values present in df
base_out <- subset(base, V1 %in% unlist(df[c(TRUE, FALSE)]))
#Create output in required format and write
cat(paste0('"', base_out$V2, '#', base_out$V1, '",'), file = 'base.lua', sep = '\n')

#Write df output
df <- data.frame(new_col = paste0('"', df[seq(2, ncol(df), 2)], '#', df[seq(1, ncol(df)-1, 2)], '"', ','))
write.table(df, file = "result.lua", sep = "#", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```

`'base.lua'` looks like this -

[image]

Comment: Absolutely perfect, thank you so much Ronak!  Works perfectly.

Comment: I have an additional question in relation to this on how to add something to it but I'll put it in a new question.