# How to merge tables and format appripriately?

Tags: r

So I have the following in cityzone.txt:

```
"earth/city/somerset/forest/somerset-test.txt#53497",
"earth/city/nottingham/forest/nighthill.txt#53498",
"earth/city/bury/town/bishop-zone1.mp3#53695",
```

And the following in areasize.txt:

```
planet\mars\red\crater.txt;56,
pluto\distant\dwarfmoon.txt;181,
mars\hot\red\redmoon.txt;43,
earth\city\somerset\forest\somerset-test.txt;205,
earth\city\bury\town\bishop-zone1.mp3;499,
```

So what I need is for a new table to be created and written to an output file.

What should happen is - for each row in cityzone.txt, the title for that row should be looked up in areasize.txt.  If the title exists, the areasize number from areasize.txt should be appended to the cityzone row like this:

```
"title#id#areasize",
```

With quotes and comma accordingly.

So for cityzones.txt above, the output should be thus:

```
"earth/city/somerset/forest/somerset-test.txt#53497#205",
"earth/city/bury/town/bishop-zone1.mp3#53695#499",
```

And then it should be output to a file with quote sand comma as shown.

So only 2 of the 3 cityzone.txt rows are included in the results because only 2 of the 3 rows exist in areasize.txt.

My starter code for this is really a continuation from this question:

[How do I merge partial data and format it in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67443607/how-do-i-merge-partial-data-and-format-it-in-r/67443663#67443663)

So I will add the code for this to the code in that question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#Read the text files and keep only 1st column
cityzone <- read.table('cityzone.txt')[1]
areasize <- read.table('areasize.txt', sep = ';')


#Separate columns on # and join
#Clean areasize dataframe
cityzone %>% separate(V1, c('V1', 'V2'), sep = '#') %>%
  inner_join(areasize %>% 
               mutate(V1 = gsub('\\\\', '/', V1), 
                      V2 = sub(',$', '', V2)), 
             by = 'V1') -> result

#Combine output in required format and write 
cat(sprintf('"%s#%s#%s",', result$V1, result$V2.x, result$V2.y), 
    file = 'output.lua', sep = '\n')
```

Comment: Damn, I'm so sorry Ronak.  Your code didn't work and when I looked why, I noticed that I'd typed out areasize.txt incorrectly.  Areasize.txt has no quotes and uses semi-colons and backslashes.  The output file should have quotes and use hash symbols and forward slashes (as shown in my desired output).  I'm sorry that was my mistake.

Comment: Maybe the updated answer would be helpful for this new data.

Comment: It's working perfect now Ronak, Thank you again.

Comment: Could I ask you one small extra thing to do with your code?  All of the rows in output.lua start with "earth/.  So I don't really need every row start with earth.  How can I make it so that output.lua omits the word 'earth' from every row?  So, for example, if the row is '"earth/city/somerset/forest/somerset-test.txt#53497#205",', then it would become "city/somerset/forest/somerset-test.txt#53497#205".

Comment: You can use `result$V1 <- sub('^earth/', '', result$V1)` before writing it with `cat`.

Comment: Perfect once again, Ronak.  This script is going to make my life so much easier.  Thank you so much.

Comment: One error - the script doesn't work (RScript reports an error) if rows in areasize.txt contain an apostrophe (').  Is it easy to fix it?  It's quite a big problem because in the current areasize.txt, there are 857 rows with apostophies  Thank you.

Comment: If you want to remove the apostrophe you can do it with `sub` like above. `result$V1 <- sub("'", "", result$V1)`

Comment: I need to keep the apostrophes in areasize.txt.  Is it possible for the script to work with the apostrophes included?

Comment: The script breaks in the '#Clean areasize dataframe' section, so subbing the single quotes after that doesn't work because the clean areasize dataframe section halts when it encounters a single quote.  The error I see is 'In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  EOF within quoted string'.  I really need to keep the single quotes in areasize.txt if possible.

Comment: Can you please ask a new question with required details and specifications? Thanks.

Comment: I added quote="\"" to read.table for areasize and it seems to have worked.  No errors reported.  Is this ok?  If you think I shouldn't be doing that, I'll raise a new question but if that looks ok, I'll leave it as it is.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know if that is ok since I don't have this new data. Check for 2-3 cases manually and if the result seems good to you it should be fine.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean, you don't have the data with the punctuation.  I understand.  It seems ok now though.  Thanks again, Ronak.